# In Cypress window.store.dispatch is not working when it is in a commands.js function

Tags: cypress

My application shows a video when starting. Then, when a product is scanned (I simulate it with window.store.dispatch) the product page information is shown.

This code loads properly the product

```
beforeEach(() =\> {
  cy.visit("/")
  cy.get('\[id="videoPlayer"\]').click()
  cy.window().then(window =\> {
    if (window.store) {
       window.store.dispatch('handlerMessageRfid', {msg: {data: JSON.stringify({result: \[{reference: '84',epc: null,serial: null}\]})}})
    }
  })
})
```

As I have to load one or several products in all my test I have tried to move it to commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getEans', (eans) =\> {
  cy.window().then(window =\> {
    if (window.store) {
      const parameter = "'handlerMessageRfid', {msg: {data: JSON.stringify({result: \[{reference: '"+ `${eans}` +"',epc: null,serial: null}\]})}}"
      window.store.dispatch(parameter)
    }
  })
})
```

Then I call the function in this way

```
beforeEach(() =\> {
  cy.visit("/")
  cy.get('\[id="videoPlayer"\]').click()
  cy.getEans('84')
})
```

I've checked that the call is being executed (with cy.log), that "if (window.store)" is true and that "window.store.dispatch(parameter)" contains a valid instruction (I have executed it outside the test), but it doesn't load anything.

Where can be the error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with the way you are passing the parameter to the window.store.dispatch function in your custom command. Instead of passing a string representation of the function call, you should pass the actual function call with the object parameter.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getEans', (eans) => {
cy.window().then((window) => {
 if (window.store) {
   window.store.dispatch('handlerMessageRfid', {
    msg: {
      data: JSON.stringify({
        result: [{ reference: eans, epc: null, serial: null }],
      }),
    },
  });
}
});
 });
```

I removed the extra single quotes and concatenation in the parameter variable. Now, you can pass the eans directly as a reference value.